# go along to ... vs. go to

Tags: meaning, adverbs, phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference if "along" in the following is omitted? What function does it serve?

> I might go along to the meeting tonight.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in meaning if *along* is omitted.

In colloquial speech, it's not uncommon to add another word to *go* or other verbs of travelling, such as *go round to* (a neighbour's house), *go over to* (a house further away), *drive down to* etc.